# Exporting NextJS site is breaking routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, next.js

I have several dynamic routes with a folder structure like this:

```
c
-> [category.js] (file)
->  [category.js] (dir)
----> [item].js (file)
----> [item].js (dir)
-------> [review].js (file)
```

This works well in development, I can reach `/c/category, /c/[category]/[item], and  /c/[category]/[item]/[review]`

I added a script to package.json: `"export": "next build && next export"`

Running next export and then uploading the "out" folder to Firebase Hosting, I am able to access the homepage and static routes, but once I try to go to any of the dynamic sites, I get a 404 error. Any idea what this may be?

Comment: I believe `[category] (dir)` does not need to have `.js` extension.
You may find more about it at the dynamic routes RFC.
https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/7607#issue-457761148

  
If you are doing static export then you may want to check this too.
https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/master/examples/with-static-export/next.config.js#L4

Comment: Every link needs to be known before production? That would make Next the worst ever